# Passing an opengl texture handle from Android Java to C++?

Tags: java, c++, android, 3d, textures

On Android, is it possible to create a texture in Java and pass its texture id/handle over through JNI to a C++ based 3d rendering engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The texture identifier to OpenGL is just an integer.  That must be interpreted in the context of a particular OpenGL client, so as long as the C++ and Java code are both operating as one client (with all OpenGL calls on a single thread) it should be possible.

Comment: Tried it. And it is possible.